# Scala idiomatic way of treating Option[DataType[Option[Boolean]]]

Tags: scala

What is the Scala idiomatic what of handling an expression of type `Option[Data[Option[Boolean]]]` when we need to know if the internal `Boolean` is true?

That's what I did:

`val isProperty: Boolean = maybeData.exists(_.isProperty.exists(a => a))`

But I feel it's not optimal. Any alternatives?

Comment: There's not much improvement to make. You can simplify a little with `maybeData.exists(_.isProperty.contains(true))`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez nice, I used maybeData.flatMap(_.isProperty).getOrElse(false). Wanna answer with it and I'll close the q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the best way to handle nested options is to *"flatten"* them into a single one using `flatMap`

```scala
val maybeProperty = maybeData.flatMap(_.isProperty)
```

Now, there are multiple ways to turn that `Option[Boolean]` into a `Boolean`

```scala
maybeProperty.contains(true)
maybeProperty.getOrElse(false)
maybeProperty.fold(ifEmpty = false)(identity)
maybeProperty.exists(identity)
maybeProperty.filter(identity).nonEmpty
```

And probably may more but they start to become more and more obscure.
I would recommend the first two; whichever you find more readable.

Comment: Just to extend that list further, there's also `maybeProperty == Some(true)`. But I agree that `contains(true)` is probably the most readable.

Comment: Cool trick of using a named argument to make the `fold` more readable 

Comment: @SethTisue yeah I probably already have a TOC with named arguments, I use them almost always except for functions.